# IIFE beginning with one parenthesis bracket not working

Tags: javascript, iife

I am looking at IIFE's in javascript, and as far as I was aware it was simply a style choice as to how you write the IIFE, and that both approaches below should work.

```
  var sum = 0
  (function test(n){
      sum += n
  }(1));
  console.log(sum);
```

This logs: `Uncaught TypeError: 0 is not a function`.

Alternatively, when I begin the IIFE with `!` it works

```
var sum = 0
  !function test(n){
      sum += n
  }(2);

  console.log(sum) //logs 2
```

As you can see when I begin the IIFE with a `!` it works as expected. I am very confused now as I thought it was simply a stylistic choice as to how you implemented the IIFE. Can anyone explain?

Comment: An easy solution is, always add a semicolon before your IIFE, if you prefer not putting semicolon for every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that you are only using one parenthesis, it's the lack of a semicolon at the end of the first line.

Look at it without the line break to see the problem.

```
var sum = 0(function test(n){
  sum += n
}(1));
```

If you follow the semicolon-free approach, then you need to guard newlines starting with `[` or `(` with a semicolon.

For example:

```
var sum = 0
;(function test(n){
  sum += n
}(1))
```

Comment: ah got it! it works now! ok, so as I should have done and used `;` when appropriate.. however, I would love to know why it worked with `!`

Comment: `0!function() {}` is not going to try and invoke `0` as though it was a function.

Comment: got it, makes sense! thanks Dan